# How to check a local wifi connection

Tags: iphone, wifi, reachability

I'm writing an app which connects to a static ip address in a local network. How can I check if I have a local network connection? I want to connect to http://192.168.2.5 and i tried using the `Rechability` class but it returns `FALSE`, while the device is definitely connected ( when i don't do the check, the app works fine so there is a connection ):

```
Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://192.168.2.5"];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
```

How should work this out?

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the impression you have not followed the usage rules as explained in the ReadMe and the sample code.
You seem to check for the status synchronously and immediately, which is not working. Look at the applicationDidFinishLaunching method in ReachabilityAppDelegate.m which shows how to wait for the answer to come in (via reachabilityChanged) before you check the status.
Also, you may need to call startNotifer to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Problem i see with this: "http://" is not a hostname ;)

You should check for your ip only without the http part!

(i know this is old, but there was no real answer and you might find this via searching)